# ggplot2: plot correct proportions using geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot proportion of diamonds using `geom_bar` and `position = "dodge"`. Here is what I have done.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = diamonds) + geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut))
```

The image below tell me how many diamonds are there for each `cut` type.

[image]

Now let's do something fancy.

```
ggplot(data = diamonds) + geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, fill = clarity), position = "dodge")
```

The image below provides count of by grouping diamonds by `clarity` for each `cut` type.

[image]

**What I would like to do is get the same dodge plot as above but showing proportion instead of count**.

For example, for `cut=ideal` and `clarity = VS2`, the proportion should be `5071/21551 = 0.23`.

Comment: No need for an additional column: `ggplot(data = diamonds) + geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = ..count../sum(..count..), fill = clarity), position = "dodge")`

Comment: @MauritsEvers That doesn't give the desired result (e.g., run it and look at the value for `cut=ideal` and `clarity=VS2` – it's not 0.23).

Comment: @Lyngbakr Ah yes, you're right! OP wants fractions *per (cut) group*. My solution gives fractions of total. In that case I would calculate fractions per group manually, and plot with `geom_bar(stat = "identity", ...)` like @Wimpel suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse)
diamonds %>%
  count(cut, clarity) %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
   mutate(Sum=sum(n)) %>% 
   mutate(proportion = n/Sum) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y=proportion, x=cut,fill=clarity)) +
   geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

create a column with the correct percentages (named "percentage"), and use

```
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)

ggplot(data = diamonds) + 
geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = percentage, fill = clarity), position = "dodge") + 
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

You can also calculate the percentage inline, as Maurits Evers suggests.

Comment: It asks for proportion not percentage.